# Cant send mail from android app using java mail api

Tags: android, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

i am trying to send an email from my android app using java mail api,
when i run the code in java project it sends mail successfully but when i use this code into android app, logcat shows error as follows :-

09-03 15:18:57.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-03 15:18:57.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{email3.app/email3.app.email3}: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;

09-03 15:18:57.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

the code is as follows :-

file1 :- email3.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class email3 extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sender s=new sender();

    }
}





file 2 :- sender.java

import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class sender {  
 public sender() {  

 String to="xxx@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

  //Get the session object  
  Properties props = new Properties();  
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
return new PasswordAuthentication("xxx@gmail.com","yyy");//change accordingly  
}  
});  

//compose message  
try {  
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxx@gmail.com"));//change accordingly  
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
message.setSubject("Hello");  
message.setText("Testing.......");  

//send message  
Transport.send(message);  


} catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}  

}  
}  




file :- 3  Menifest file

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".email3"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</application>
```

Comment: Send Mail id Background Like Asyanktask

Comment: Have you tried sending email through asynctask?And what your logcat says exactly?

Comment: look above....there is the exact error showing by logcat

Comment: Start by fixing all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, 
all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*"

Use `props.put("mail.smtp.port", "888");`  to set the mail.smtp.port property, which is of type int.

Comment: so now what should i do, tell where should i do change in code

Comment: i changed every "smtp" to "smtps" but it doesnt working so now what should i do, tell where should i do change in code

Comment: Have you added following permission on menifest?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: i just added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission after you said, when i run app on mobile phone it shows error "Permission denied(missing internet permission?)" which i explicitly print using Exception class's getMessage(); and when i run app on emulator it shows error "could not connect to smtp host: smtp.gmail.com; post:465"

Comment: Have you provide <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: yes mr. Hacker Celluloid, and now i get out with this issue and have a working code, anyway thanks