# sending mail by android app using javamail api without user interaction

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I am making an android app in which i have to send some text by mail, i tried many codes but they working in java project but not in android project, i searched and tried almost all the posts here and also everywhere on internet but no one is working, can anybody please give me the working code to send mail by java mail API in android, i have almost completed my app except this mail part. so please help me to get out this issue.

logcat error is as follow:-

09-03 22:41:58.636: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

and the interesting thing is that my app getting different errors on different devices (printstack errors),
when i run the app on emulator then i get the error as

"Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gamil.com, port:587"

and

when i run the app on my android mobile phone then i get the error as:-

"permission denied(missing INTERNET permission?)"

and i already gives the INTERNET permission in manifest file.

the code which i already tried is at following link :-

Visit [Cant send mail from android app using java mail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641220/cant-send-mail-from-android-app-using-java-mail-api)

and

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088195/application-has-closed-unexpecteadly-forse-closed

Comment: I am working on a tutorial to show how to do this; meanwhile, you should download commons-email.jar, mail.jar, activation.jar and additional.jar files then write your own client.

Comment: yes sir i have downloaded that 3 jar files and added them into my project, but i am getting error as "Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gamil.com, port:587" on emulator and "permission denied(missing INTERNET permission?)" on android mobile phone

Comment: yes, i gave both INTERNET permission and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission :)

Comment: Post your manifest. Looks like you misspelled it. Also, post your email sending code (just the basics, as well as the invocation). I smell a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: The code is here sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088195/application-has-closed-unexpecteadly-forse-closed

Comment: no its inside the <application> tag, anyway now i get out from this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

Once you have downloaded and add these jar files : **commons-email.jar, mail.jar, activation.jar and additional.jar**, you should be able to send emails in the background.

1. First, create an AsyncTask so that you can send the email in the background. Then inside **doInBackground**, add the following code - replace the values as needed.

   ```
   public class EmailSenderAsync extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Boolean> {

     private HtmlEmail email;


     @Override
     protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
     {
       String textMsg;
       try {
          String userEmail = params[0];
          String message = param[1];

          email = new HtmlEmail();

          email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("youremail@yahoo.com",   "yourpasswordhere"));

          email.setSmtpPort(587);

          email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

          email.setDebug(true);


          email.addTo(userEmail, "Whatever you want here");

          email.setFrom("youremail@yahoo.com", "Your business name");

          email.setSubject("Your email subject here");


          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.port", "587");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "587");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class",  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

          email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

          email.setTextMsg(message);

          email.send();


          return true;

       } catch (Exception e){

          return false;
       }

   }
   ```

Now you can call it from wherever you need to send an email by doing this:

```
new EmailSenderAsync().execute("useremail@gmail.com", "Thank you for contacting us this morning");
```

That will solve your problem.

Good luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: i think to "protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)", we should write like "protected Boolean doInBackground(String[] params)", am i right Mr. Eenvincible?? or if i am wrong then explain me the correct value as parameters

Comment: Normally, if it worked, you would mark this as the answer by accepting it. Thanks and I also glad I could help

Comment: i marked your answer for the best up but it says "vote up requires 15 reputation" :(